# Blocking certain words from being sent

Tags: c#

recently I have had many people posting url's to their games into my game server and now decided to code a world filter system, so its a database table with lots of words in it. What the problem is, is that they keep bypassing it.. like below

```
I first blocked "universegames.com"
```

they post u niversegames.com

```
I then blocked "u niversgames.com"
```

they posted un    iversalgames.com

do you get what I am saying? is there any better way to do this other than blocking them all 1 by 1? they keep adding gaps and symbols inbetween etc..

Comment: You don't know how to trim white-space from a string?

Comment: Like I said they keep adding gaps AND symbols

Comment: So how do you (informally) determine what's valid and what isn't?

Comment: I add them 1 by 1 if its a rival game site? What I want to do is get all the 1 by 1's from a db and sort of remove the symbols and white spaces and try and get the real link behind the symbols blocking it?

Comment: You might try checking if a string is similar to an already blocked string through one of these methods: http://stackoverflow.com/a/577551/2622972

Comment: [Blacklists don't scale well](https://blog.codinghorror.com/blacklists-dont-work/).  They also can have many [unintended consequences](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Scunthorpe_problem).