# SQL Server : searching duplicate record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to check for duplicate bame in SQL Server.

Table **Company**:

```
   CompanyName            | Business
   -----------------------+----------
   Example Company INC    | Telecom 
   The Example Company    | Telecom
```

I want to get the both of the company name as duplicate. using the parameters "The Example Company INC".

When I use

```
SELECT CompanyName 
FROM COMPANY 
WHERE CompanyName LIKE '%The Example Company INC%'
```

it show no results. The query must return 2 records - is this possible?

Comment: You can check like this `SELECT CompanyName FROM COMPAY 
    WHERE CompanyName LIKE '%Example Company%' `

Comment: your table name is wrong i think it should be COMPANY.

Comment: please check your table name and you should remove INC from Where clause.

Comment: sorry typo I'll edit the question

Comment: @RaviMatani The parameter is as is.. and should return 2 records..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string and Go with Dynamic coding

```
DECLARE @QRY VARCHAR(MAX), @DIVISIONS  VARCHAR(MAX)='The Example Company INC';

    DECLARE @START INT=1, @END INT=LEN(@DIVISIONS)
    , @LIKE VARCHAR(MAX)='CompanyName LIKE ''%';

    WHILE (@START<=@END)
    BEGIN

    SELECT @LIKE =@LIKE+  CASE ASCII(SUBSTRING(@DIVISIONS, @START, 1))
        WHEN 32
            THEN '%'' OR CompanyName LIKE ''%'
        ELSE SUBSTRING(@DIVISIONS, @START, 1)
        END

    SET @START+=1

    END
    SET @LIKE = @LIKE+'%'''

    SELECT @QRY = ' SELECT CompanyName FROM COMPANY 
    WHERE ' + @LIKE

    PRINT @QRY


    EXEC(@QRY)
```

Another simple way of Dynamic Query:

```
DECLARE @QRY VARCHAR(MAX), @DIVISIONS  VARCHAR(MAX)='The Example Company INC'
,@LIKE VARCHAR(MAX)='CompanyName LIKE ''%';

DECLARE @END INT=LEN(@DIVISIONS)
select @LIKE = @LIKE+   CASE ASCII(SUBSTRING(@DIVISIONS, number, 1))
        WHEN 32
        THEN '%'' OR CompanyName LIKE ''%'
ELSE SUBSTRING(@DIVISIONS, number, 1)
END
FROM master.dbo.spt_values 
where type='p' and number between 1 and @END

SET @LIKE = @LIKE+'%'''
SELECT @QRY = ' SELECT CompanyName FROM COMPANY 
WHERE ' + @LIKE

PRINT @QRY


EXEC(@QRY)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I was also trying to split the strings. but I'm not that good at tsql. Thanks again.

Comment: Shakeer Mirza can you explain this line of code me..  "CASE ASCII(SUBSTRING(@DIVISIONS, number, 1))
        WHEN 32"   Thanks.

Comment: Its Just checking the character is Space or not. 32 is the ascii value of Space character @Alvie

Comment: Thanks Shakeer Mirza.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the only case where one company is 'Example Company INC' and another company is 'The Example Company' then the following query can work

```
SELECT CompanyName FROM COMPANY WHERE CompanyName LIKE '%Example Company%'
```

But i think there can be many companies with different names. So in this case, I think for you the best is to find the similarity between two strings. And on the base of similarity factor you can decide whether they are same or not.

If your case is second one then this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577463/finding-how-similar-two-strings-are) can help you

Comment: The second one is correct.  I need to find if the string are somewhat similar. On the example i have given the words "The" and "INC"  are making the string unique.